# Can't open module windows in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 macros in my ribbon, all located in my personal macro workbook.  They are no longer running when I click the buttons.  I get the error

> Macro may not be available or all macros may be disabled"

I do have my macros enabled.

When I open up the IDE I can see my modules under my personal workbook, however, when I double click on one or try to open one, the code window never pops up.  Just started happening recently.  I can open macros In other workbooks.

I have tried re-saving the file under a different name but still can't see them. File is saved as XLSB. The location is trusted in the trust center and the macro settings are on "disable with notification".

I expect to be able to double click a module and have a window pop up for me to access my code.

Comment: I have found that VBA is great at corrupting itself. is fetching the code from an older version of the project a possibility? I have had to do this many times in the past. You may have a different issue here, though.

Comment: Combee If your suggested issue was the problem.  How would I go about fixing it?

Comment: Dustin, in my case, I deleted the corrupted part of the project and recreated it from existing backups that I regularly make due to VBA's ability to corrupt the files. If you don't have backups, you may try something like this:
https://superuser.com/questions/657217/recovering-vba-modules-from-corrupt-excel-workbook